# How to set a max rows on Telerik Grid (MVC, Razor)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik

Is there a way to set a maximum of rows on a Telerik Grid?

For example, i just want to let the customer introduce 15 rows max or a minimum of 1 or throwing an error that the maximum its "x".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to solve this.

```
.ClientEvents(x => {
    x.OnEdit("CheckRows");
    x.OnDelete("CheckRows"); })

<script>
 function CheckRows(e) {   
        var grid = $('#Grid').data('tGrid');
        var button = $("#Grid .t-grid-toolbar .t-grid-add");
        if (grid.insertedDataItems().length - grid.deletedDataItems().length > 15) 
        {
            button.hide();
        }
        else
        {
            button.show();
        }
      }
</script>
```

Comment: Such validation should be on server side. In your case client can show your button with browser programmer tool and submit you data against validation.